# Javascript: How to properly check if array is empty

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to validate my array input fields if its empty, unfortunately my code seems not working i don't know why, and what is the best way to validate this.

```
<input type="text" name="sub_crit_text[]" class="sub_crit_text" value="text1">
<input type="text" name="sub_crit_text[]" class="sub_crit_text" value="text2">
<input type="text" name="sub_crit_text[]" class="sub_crit_text" value="text3">
<input type="text" name="sub_crit_text[]" class="sub_crit_text" value="text4">
```

My js

```
var sub_crit_arr = [];
$('.sub_crit_text').each(function(k , v){
    sub_crit_arr[k] = $(v).val();
});

if(sub_crit_arr.length > 0){

}else{
    alert('Sub criteria cannot be empty');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Not working in the sense? what is happening?

Comment: sub_crit_arr.length > 0 You are just checking to see if the array has a length, you are not checking to see if they inputs actually have a value.

Comment: Just so you know, that's not the correct way to fill an array. Do `sub_crit_arr.push($(v).val())` instead of `sub_crit_arr[k] = $(v).val()`.

Comment: @MikeC thanks for that idea

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it with `filter` alone,

```
if($('.sub_crit_text').filter(function(){ return !this.value.trim(); }).length){
    alert('Sub criteria cannot be empty');
    return false;
}
```

There is no need to introduce another one array and also you can cut down one more iteration.

Answer (score 3):

An array of empty strings will give you a length greater than 0:

```
var sub_crit_arr = ['','','','']
```

Try `filter`ing the results first:

```
sub_crit_arr.filter(function(element){
  return element // empty string is falsy
}).length
```

Comment: @Rajesh textbox's values always be string, not boolean.

Answer (score 1):

`Array.filter` will give you element and not boolean value. If you just want to just validate and do not have use for invalid entries, you can use `array.some` or `array.every`

#### Array.every

```js
$("#btnValidate").on("click", function(){
  var valid = [].every.call($(".sub_crit_text"), function(el){
    return el.value.trim().length > 0
  });
  console.log(valid)
})
```

```css
sub_crit_text
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="sub_crit_text[]" class="sub_crit_text" value="text1">
<input type="text" name="sub_crit_text[]" class="sub_crit_text" value="text2">
<input type="text" name="sub_crit_text[]" class="sub_crit_text" value="text3">
<input type="text" name="sub_crit_text[]" class="sub_crit_text" value="text4">
<button id="btnValidate">Validate</button>
```

#### Array.some

```js
$("#btnValidate").on("click", function(){
  var inValid = [].some.call($(".sub_crit_text"), function(el){
    return el.value.trim().length === 0
  });
  console.log(inValid);
})
```

```css
sub_crit_text
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="sub_crit_text[]" class="sub_crit_text" value="text1">
<input type="text" name="sub_crit_text[]" class="sub_crit_text" value="text2">
<input type="text" name="sub_crit_text[]" class="sub_crit_text" value="text3">
<input type="text" name="sub_crit_text[]" class="sub_crit_text" value="text4">
<button id="btnValidate">Validate</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you simply want to check if one of the input is empty :

**JS**

```
var valid = false ;

$('.sub_crit_text').each(function(k , v){
  if ( $(v).val() ) valid = true ;
});

if (!valid)
  alert("Sub criteria cannot be empty");
```

Be aware that all the input has value at first. So maybe it is the reason your code not work.